# React: Using Theme UI and Material UI together

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a project that is using Theme UI and wanting to bring in Material UI to a React 18 project. However, I'm running into trouble just using the standalone components. The documentation seems to be out of ideas.

Here's a CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-frost-5n1mlc-5n1mlc?file=/index.tsx

What am I missing?

Comment: They both leverage Emotion's theme provider, but their theme structures are not compatible. You can surround the MUI part with MUI's ThemeProvider, but I don't think you will be able to use both MUI and Theme UI within the same part of your element hierarchy.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Ah, bummer. This is what I was afraid of. So whatever component I'd have, I'd have to indivudually wrap it around the Material UI theme provider?